# Problems with a 3 column layout with fixed left side

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a problem making a 3 column layout. I have tried all examples now online - used Google. None of this seems to solve my problem.

What I try to do is easy for people with knowledge.

1. Make a 3 column fluid layout that cover the whole screen.
2. Left column should be 230px width, fixed, height 100%.
3. Center column and right column should be equal width.
4. For both center - and right column they have to "float" into each other

Problem occur when you zoom out. Center column run away to left and make a huge white gap between center column and right column.

That is my problem.

center and right column need to be close to each other - no gap.

How can I solve this?

You can see my attempt here: **[`Fiddle`](http://www.jsfiddle.net/AgKse/)**

Just zoom out, and you see the problem straight away. Need help to fix this. How?

Another problem occur if I use a div wrapper inside the center column with width set to 100%. Same problem as described above will happened. The text in both left and right column need to be float as well.

I can't use `overflow:hidden` because I need to - later - use a absolute div on right side of the center column to set a image arrow pointing to right column.

Comment: Please put your code from fiddle into the question too.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean in point 4? Your use of the word float is confusing in this context as technically in CSS it means something different to what I think you think it does.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AgKse/

Comment: Just try to zoom in and out and you see my problem. As mentioned in number 4, they need to float into each other, not the white gap that occur when you zoom

Comment: Try to post at least *some* of the relevant code into the question itself, rather than just linking to a JSFiddle. This can be done by clicking the 'edit' button on your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gbRzM/?
(uses left, right and width properties to position everything)

```
.left {
    width: 230px;
position:fixed;
    background:GREEN;
}

.right {
    right:0;
    width:30%;
    position:fixed;
    background: RED;
}

.center {
    left:230px;
    right:30%;
    position:fixed;
    border:1px solid;
    background:YELLOW;
}
```

Or more accurately this: http://jsfiddle.net/HKJvP/?
(puts center and right in a new div, so that pixels and % can be mixed, allows equal width that you specified)

```
.left {
    width: 230px;
    position:fixed;
    background:GREEN;
}

.notleft{
    left:230px;
    height:100%;
    right:0;
    position:fixed;
}

.right {
    right:0;
    width:50%;
    position:absolute;
    background: RED;
}

.center {
    left:0;
    width:50%;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid;
    background:YELLOW;
}
```

Comment: #dave. The last example is what I mean yes, and it works. thanks

Comment: If this answered your question, click the checkmark and mark it as accepted. Also, you can use the @ sign to tag previous commenters and notify them, like so: @RachelleCasamilloFlashlight

Answer (score 0):

give a fixed width to the parent element of three columns and add class clearfix

``

```
.clearfix:after {     
    content: ".";    
    display: block;    
    clear: both;  
    visibility: hidden;  
    line-height: 0;   
    height: 0;   
}   

.clearfix {   
    display: inline-block;  
}   

html[xmlns] .clearfix {    
    display: block;    
}    

* html .clearfix {     
    height: 1%;      
}
```