# How can I remove absolute div in column layout and keep same layout?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I asked a question earlier today and got a answer I accepted, and it seems to work, except the problem that occur when the column content become larger than browser window because I can't scroll down.

Is there any way to get same result as given in my accepted answer in previous question, without use of absolute values?

This is the problem that I need help to solve

[Link to previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307009/problems-with-a-3-column-layout-with-fixed-left-side)

Link to jFiddler that show the problem jsfiddle.net/HKJvP/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this one

HTML

```
<div class="left-fixed">
    Left side here!
</div>
<div class="floating-container">
    <div class="left">
        Center Fluid<br/>
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Right '200px width'<br/>

        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, html{
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin: 0;
}

.left-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 230px;
    background-color: green;
}

.floating-container {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 230px;
}

.floating-container .left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.floating-container .right {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w5Jvw/1/)

Comment: Allmost. A few strange things happend. When midle column - left - get a lot of content and you scroll down, it jump out of the column. Right column should have equal hight as left column.

Comment: I tried. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/w5Jvw/2/

As you see the right column. The center follow along here, but in my html file it all happend.

Comment: @RachelleCasamilloFlashlight Try this one http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w5Jvw/7/

Comment: lot of strange things. Hard to show it on jsfiddler, but just copy the code in a html file and zoom in and out.

Comment: is it the red color at the bottom

Comment: Try adding `min-height: 100%;` to `.floating-container table`

Comment: Seems to work okey no, except I had to set margin-left:-40px for both left columns. Reason? If you make a div width 100% width, it will be 40px far out to right

Comment: More bugs here. Look at this and try to zoom. http://jsfiddle.net/w5Jvw/11/. if you remove text, or no text in the column. The column vanish. Everything floats to left side, not fluid it seems. And the left_box I made, are overflowing the right column

Answer (score 0):

This is the css you should be looking at....display: should be inline.... This is for two colums... do the same thing for 3 columns.... and another thing don't set the height. It should be automatically increasing with content....It helps for dynamic pages too...

```
                .wrapper{overflow:hidden; width:90%; padding:30px; margin:0 0 0 5%; }
               .wrapper .right {width: 80%;
                             padding-right: 20px;
                               float: right;
                              display: inline;
                          border: solid #000 1px 2px 2px 1px;
                        padding:10px;
                              }


            .wrapper .leftbar {
                 width: 15%;
                float: left;
           display: inline; padding:10px;
                 }
```

Comment: @user1978166 This css code give me the same problem as mentioned in my first question, and solved with absolute.

Comment: @user1978166  Look at this. http://jsfiddle.net/w5Jvw/6/.   Problem also occur if you have a box in the midle column and set width to 100%.

Comment: The code's alright . Just change the width of right to 70%...it is getting larger than wrapper that's the prob... everything works fine....I just checked the jsfiddle file you said....<div class="wrapper"><div class="leftbar"></div<div class="right"></div> </div>....works fine....